# Java classes and constructors

Tags: java, class, constructor, instances

I hope this won't sound like a stupid question.

I have a class A and a class B. Now the only thing B has is a String ID.
Now I can have multiple objects A that each can have 0 or more objects of type B. 
These are contained in a HashMap(ID,someData) each class A has.

What I want to do is each time I add a new ID in class A to check whether there already
is a on object of Type B with the same ID in any of the other class A objects I have, and if not, create a new B object.

Hope this makes sense. If what I ask is wrong is some way, please be kind enough to explain 
how is this a bad practice or conceptualy wrong.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:To be more clear,in my case, it is not desireable to share the HashMap(ID,someData) for all my objects as for example let's say A is a Course class,Or Catalogue, or Bank etc. Each A class may share some students/clients but each A class may contain different class B objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not bad practice, it seems like you're implementing the [Instance Manager Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InstanceManagerPattern).

> - Ability to look up one or more instances (via a key) of the managed object(s). If only one managed object, then a key is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you need to do this is to have a collection of all A objects so you can check them all.  As you get more A objects this will become more inefficient. A diiferent was to structure this might be to use the ID as you collection.

```
Map<ID,/* class with A and someData *> map = ...
```

This allows you to ensure uniqueness of ID across all A.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your purpose, you can make the HashMap a `static` variable, instead of an instance variable. Therefore, it will be shared among all instance of Class A.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would have created a B_Factory class. This class would be responsible for creating the B objects. A class objects would call B_Factory methods to add or delete a B object. Inside B_Factory, you could use a Map to store the instances of B objects.

There should be only one instance of B_Factory class, which will be injected in all A instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through all your A instances and use Hashmaps containsKey method to check that the new B value is already stored or not. If you only need to store all the B values to every A class only once, you can add a static modifier for your HashMap field.